# A proved computationally-irreductible function

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, computability, cellular-automata, universal-turing-machines

In [arXiv:1111.4121](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4121) and [arXiv:1304.5247](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.5247), Hervé Zwirn and Jean-Paul Delahaye propose a formal definition of computational irreducibility. Is there a (possibly artificial) function that can be proved to be computationally irreducible? I would accept an answer based on an alternative formal definition.